# How to receive path from internal storage in android and transform it into view?

Tags: android, picasso, android-internal-storage

I'm new to android development and I've been building an app for studies purposes that is supposed to display one of the images selected from the gallery previously in a recyclerview.

```
private fun configDocImageDialog(pathGallery: Int, pathCamera: Int) {
        MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(requireContext())
            .setTitle(getString(R.string.camera_or_gallery))
            .setMessage(getString(R.string.image_path))
            .setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.gallery)) { _, _ ->
                val intent = Intent()
                intent.type = "image/*"
                intent.action = Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select: "), pathGallery)
            }.setNegativeButton(getString(R.string.camera)) { _, _ ->
                val intent = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Take: "), pathCamera)
            }.setNeutralButton(getString(R.string.cancel)) { dialog, _ ->
                dialog.dismiss()
            }.show()
    }
```

Not I'm not worried about the camera result.
Then receiving the result as:

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            val selectedImage = data!!.data
            val pathImage = selectedImage.toString()
            try {
                when (requestCode) {
                    GALLERY_1 -> {
                        binding.imageDoc1.setImageURI(selectedImage)
                    }
                    CAMERA_1 -> {
                        binding.imageDoc1.setImageURI(selectedImage)
                    }
                    GALLERY_2 -> {
                        binding.imageDoc2.setImageURI(selectedImage)
                    }
                    CAMERA_2 -> {
                        binding.imageDoc2.setImageURI(selectedImage)
                    }
                    GALLERY_3 -> {
                        binding.imageDoc3.setImageURI(selectedImage)
                    }
                    CAMERA_3 -> {
                        binding.imageDoc3.setImageURI(selectedImage)
                    }
                }
                imageList.add(pathImage)
            } catch (e: Exception){
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
        }
    }
```

I received as a result from the intent a list with this kind of content:

```
content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A20
```

And those are saved into the database, the list of paths. /
Is it possible to use this path to my exhibit the image in my adapter? I've been trying different treatments but it always blank.
I've trying to use Picasso as:

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: DocViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val doc = docs[position]
        holder.binding.apply {
            Picasso.get()
                .load(doc.docImageList[0])
                .into(imageDoc)
            textDocName.text = doc.title
            textValidity.text = doc.validity
        }
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
            onItemClickListener?.let {
                it(doc)
            }
        }
    }
```

I want to display an image from internal storage in a recyclerview but the image is always blank.
Any ideas how to do it properly? Thanks

Comment: Do not mess around with the File class. Just give that content scheme uri to Picasso. Thats all.

Comment: Or: imageDoc.loadFromUri(uri).

Comment: I've tried to use only ".load(doc.docImageList[0])" but it still blank..

Comment: Do you think we would know what doc.docImageList[0] would deliver? Well i dont know what that would be. Post your problem in such a way that we know what you do.

Comment: It is there.. said that the content of the list is one of above: "content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A20" as the content of the list. This is the path that I'm receiving and not able to handle as an image.

Comment: So it is a String list. Not an Uri list? You should better show what you have. Dont talk but put that content scheme in your code so we see what you do.

Comment: I updated with all the information about it. Sorry about that, it was not clear at all. I hope it helps to understand what I did.

Comment: Much too much code. And still we do not see that content scheme. And you still have that doc.docImageList[0] instead of that content scheme uri. Sorry u will not follow all that code.

Comment: And if binding.imageDoc1.setImageURI(selectedImage) works in inActivityResult... Then what is the problem later? Why do you use Picasso then?. I suggested before to use setImageUri().

Comment: Now I understood what you mean, sorry about that.. I'm new to android and English is not my first language.. I struggled a little bit. I did what you said and now I'm able to find the document that I'm trying to recover, but it happened:
Permission Denial: opening provider com.android.providers.media.MediaDocumentsProvider

Comment: So the content scheme can be used in onActivityResult. But the same content scheme does not work later!? Is that what it is?